# C Programming Error: too few arguments to function "whatever's inside"

Tags: c, function

These Functions should work but why aren't they? The compiler says Error: too few arguments to function "whatever's inside". I am a beginner to C so forgive my stupidness. I would also like to know what can be in a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int x;
int y;

int multiply (int x, int y)
{
    printf("()");
    return x*y;
    getchar();
    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf(":\n", multiply(x, y));

}

int add (int x, int y)
{
    printf("()");
    return x+y;
    getchar();
    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf(":\n", add(x, y));
}

int divide (int x, int y)
{
    printf("()");
    return x/y;
    getchar();
    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf(":\n", divide(x, y));
}

int subtract(int x, int y)
{
    printf("()");
    return x-y;
    getchar();
    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf(":\n", divide(x, y));
}

int power(int x, int y)
{
    printf("()");
    pow(x, y);
    getchar();
    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf(":\n", power(x, y));
}

//main code

int main(void)
{
    int option;

    switch (option)
    {
    case 1:
    add();
    break;

    case 2:
    subtract();
    break;

    case 3:
    multiply();
    break;

    case 4:
    divide();
    break;

    case 5:
    power();
    break;


    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: You are calling the functions in main(void) without any values ... ex. add() should be something like add(1,1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int multiply (int x, int y)
{
    return x*y;
}

int add (int x, int y)
{
    return x+y;
}

int divide (int x, int y)
{
    return x/y;
}

int subtract(int x, int y)
{
    return x-y;
}

int power(int x, int y)
{
    return pow(x, y);
}

//main code

int main(void)
{
    int option, result, x, y;
    printf("Enter the numbers:\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
    printf("1. Add\n2. Subtract\n3. Multiplu\n4. Divide\n5. Power\nEnter your choice:\t");
    scanf("%d",&option);
    switch (option)
    {
    case 1:
    result = add(x,y);
    break;

    case 2:
    result = subtract(x,y);
    break;

    case 3:
    result = multiply(x,y);
    break;

    case 4:
    result = divide(x,y);
    break;

    case 5:
    result = power(x,y);
    break;


    }
    printf("\nRequired result = %d",result);
    getchar();
}
```

You might want to include some condition in your code like division by `0` shouldn't be allowed, et cetra.

Answer (score 1):

You havent passed any parameters to the functions.

Also, if you are intending to use global variables, dont use global names for local variables like parameters to the functions

eg:

```
add(1,2);
subtract(1,2)
```

Also, the part after **return** doesnt get executed cuz you have returned immediately

Answer (score 0):

Just pass some correct values to functions while calling them. eg, when you call add(); call it like : **add(5, 4)**

And, just remove void from main(**void**).

It will work. and do vote up if you like answer.